# Angular: Add open button for ng-datepicker button

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am trying to add simple button to open this datepicker calendar as it only shows an input box

```
< ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="dateEnd"  [options]="options" #datepickerEnd name="datepickerEnd" (ngModelChange)="ChangedatepickerDateEnd()"  ></ng-datepicker >
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: this is a lib for angularjs, at least when I googled?

Comment: I am trying to associate a  button that will open the datepicker,

Comment: this is the component
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker

I am trying to associate a  button that will open the datepicker
but I cant make it work.

                                    <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="datepickerEnd">
                                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                     </label>